# Firebase authentication process for Python desktop application

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, pyqt

I want some help with the database implementation in my project.

The final implementation:
Website:
I want to make a (flask) website where the user can create or delete an account.
Desktop application:
I also want to make a (PyQt) python application that the user can log in to his/her account via a login prompt.
Database:
I want to make a (firebase) database so the users can authenticate. The database will also collect some user information except the authentication credentials.

The implementation until now:
Firebase:
I created a “web app” in firebase so I communicate with firebase via firebaseConfig

Flask website:
I created a flask website that communicates with the firebase via the firebaseConfig. The user fills in a form, and the firebase authentication creates a user via (create_user_with_email_and_password). The database, also, collects some extra user information.
(I think that my code is “safe” as it is server-side)

The problem:

Python application:
I created a python application that the user can log in to the firebase authentication. The problem I faced is that I “have to” include the firebaseConfig in my python code. With the firebaseConfig I can create and delete users, but I don’t want the other users to have the ability to do this.
(so I think my code is unsafe because the communication with the firebase is client-side so someone may decompile the code and get the firebaseConfig).

What is the best way to make my project safer?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the Firebase Admin SDK for Python, which (like all Admin SDKs) runs with elevated privileges and should only be used in trusted environments (such as *your* development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run).

There is no Firebase-provided SDK for use in Python applications that you ship to regular users of your app. That means that your options are limited to either using the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) to sign in with Firebase, or to use a 3rd party library, such as [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#authentication) (be sure to **not** use a service account there, as that'd make it run with the same elevated privileges as the Admin SDK).